# After 3 number at input filed, inset automatically "-" and set the limit to 9 characters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

As i said at, i want to do something like this. If the user input numbers and text like this, 4J6354DRQ  to automatically show like this `4J6-354-DRQ` and if this is achieved show a <kbd>send</kbd> button.

Comment: Input where? Show where? Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: hi, sorry for not giving details, l have created the form just in html, but i want a condition do to do just the exchange from "4J6354DRQ" to "4J6-354-DRQ"

Comment: Try it how you think it should be done, and if it doesn't work as intended, post the code you tried along with how it's not working as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
"4J6354DRQ".substr(0, 9).match(/.{1,3}/g).join("-");
```

Limit to 9 chars, cut at every 3rd char and join it with a hyphen.

Comment: hi, i dont want a static number, it depends on what user types in, thank you for responding .

Comment: So just add a variable like `userInput.substr(0, 9).match(/.{1,3}/g).join("-");` ?

Comment: What is your exact problem? Do you know how to get the users input?

Comment: Can you please explain it to me, or at least show me how it is done ? Thank you

Comment: HTML: `<input type="text" id="myText" />`, JS: `document.getElementById('myText').value.substr(0, 9).match(/.{1,3}/g).join("-");`

Comment: and one more thing, when the user start typing it will automaticlly get the "-" or i should add also a  button on click ?

Comment: I'm sorry that it doesnt work but you cannot expect others to fix your problem when its totally unclear what you are expecting. For your current problem I gave you a possible solution (which is working for this case), everything else is another topic.

Comment: sorry for being intrusive, and thank you for your help, i will work on that, bt i just need one more thing, not allowing special characters and spaces, if you please...?